# CREATE TABLE in MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

i am trying to use the db to link it with my java project 
and i am using wampsarver to create the db.
what should i do to fix this please .

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') NOT NULL , `Phone` DOUBLE( 20 ) NOT NULL , `Id` INT( 20 ) NOT
>   NULL AUTO_INCR' at line 6

```
CREATE TABLE `Laptop` (
`serial number ` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Device Model` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Device Manufacturer` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Device Color` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Screen size` DOUBLE( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Phone` DOUBLE( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Id` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
UNIQUE (
`serial number ` 
)
) ENGINE = innodb
```

Comment: Are you really in the habit of putting the auto_increment primary key as the last column in the table?  Usually, this is first.

Comment: Spaces in Column Names are not recommended either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For double you have to add another digit after comma for precision.Also No space is allowed after name.the following script is working

```
 CREATE TABLE `Laptop` (
 `serial number` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Device Model` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Device Manufacturer` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Device Color` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Screen size` DOUBLE( 20,4 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Phone` DOUBLE( 20,4 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Id` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  UNIQUE (
 `serial number` 
  )
  ) ENGINE = innodb
```

Answer (score 3):

`DOUBLE` requires precision too ( I gave `DOUBLE(20,2)` - change it as needed).

Plus there was a stray space at the end of `serial number` column name.

```
CREATE TABLE `Laptop` (
`serial number` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Device Model` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Device Manufacturer` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Device Color` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Screen size` DOUBLE( 20,2) NOT NULL ,
`Phone` DOUBLE( 20 ,2) NOT NULL ,
`Id` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
UNIQUE (
`serial number` 
)
)
```

Also, it's better to use `DECIMAL` instead of `DOUBLE` as the doubles can't be represented exactly and creates problem while doing comparisons.